# Testing methods called from another method

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd

I have a class with a method called `DataIn(int InputID, string CSVValue)`, this is the main entry point to it.

This method based on the `InputID` stores the CSV Value parameter into relevant `List<string>'s`. When the `InputID` is the same as a property called `NoOfRows` it then creates one `List<string>` made up of all the others.  It then checks the validity of this final `List<string>`, if all is ok then it adds the results to a `HashSet<int>` as a quick way of checking for duplicates.

I have broken this logic into 3 methods so DataIn calls StoreData, when the InputID in DataIn = NoOfRows it calls MergeData which calls ValidateData.

My question is should I make these methods public to test them separately or should I keep them private and pass in data to DataIn and the do asserts on the merged data `List<string>` and the `HashSet<int>`. DataIn will be the method that is called from outside the class, making the other methods public would only be for unit testing.

My concern is that if I make the other methods public and test they are ok I am then not testing DataIn works as expected or if I do both I end up with duplicate tests.

What's your advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always stick to the `principle of least privilege`. Exposing private methods as public just to make them unit testable is not a good design. Instead, stick to testing the `public interfaces` only. If a method behaves in multiple ways with different inputs, make sure that you write a test per behavior expected and you should a neat and clean design, while still being well tested.

Comment: What if I have 2 public methods with similar logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354729/how-to-test-2-methods-with-common-logic by doing that I'd have to test the same logic twice. What should I do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

There are two competing schools of thought on the need to test private methods - one says that you *should not* test them, because they are an implementation detail; the other says that you *should* test them, because you need to test everything.

Without getting in the middle of the argument between the two, I should mention that both sides have valid points going for their approach. However, one thing you should definitely avoid is making your would-be private methods public for the sole purpose of testing them. If you decide to go with the "test private methods" approach, you should make these methods *internal*, not *public*, and let the testing assembly see the internal methods using the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute in your target assembly.