# should the controller talk to the presenter?

Tags: architecture, software-design, clean-architecture

In the [Clean Architecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WpkDN78P884) by Robert Martin, let's say I have this simplified version (not showing other stuff like Model, Gateway, Boundaries):

[image]

Now let's say I have a `View` with 2 buttons, `Dark` and `Light`, that when clicked should change the background color of the `View` and show some text on the screen (the text's color should always be blue).
So I though of something like this:

[image]

Assuming here that I have to use one method in the controller for both buttons (maybe because it was a form or whatever), the `button` variable in `buttonClicked(button)` will contain the information on whether the `Dark` or `Light` button was pressed.

Now, the `Interactor` in this case is only responsible for retrieving the text to be displayed, but it doesn't need to know anything about the background color.

So, should the controller tell the presenter which color (i.e. button) was chosen or should I relay this information to the `Interactor` just so that it can pass it to the `Presenter`? Keeping in mind that the `Interactor` won't even use this information.

Comment: @ctietze what do you think about this?

Comment: I think the dependency circle you are drawing here violates the clean architectures main idea. Your interactor should not know anything about the controller or the presenter or the view. This is what these typical circle drawings mean, when talking about clean architecture. See [Uncle Bob's original blog post](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html)